# Bubbles in unopened store bought items?

Tags: canning

I've noticed air bubbles in several things I've purchased recently. From pasta sauce to salad dressings to salsa.  All different brands, all different flavors.  I see air bubbles inside the jars/bottles, and I wonder why this is, and if it's normal.  Are these items safe to eat?

Comment: Technically, there's a large "bubble" at the top of every jar, as the jars aren't filled to the top.

Comment: Bubbles can be caused simply by agitation.

Comment: So this would not be a botulism risk?

Comment: No the containers are completely sealed.  I just found it odd that they had bubbles as I've not noticed that before.

Answer (score 1):

1.Some companies when they pack would fill it with a air form of preservatives.

2.Other reason for the bubbles could also be simple air that was trapped when it was packed or sealed in the container or packet. And maybe the container/packet was shaken up a bit when dispatched, causing the air inside to move around in the product.

should have no effect on the product. Just trust the best before date. (Unless it tastes funny) :)

Comment: Thank you so much- that makes sense.  I guess I was trying to reason out why the bubbles would be there.  I have a fear of botulism that I know is irrational and it has prevented me from eating normally for years.  Working on overcoming it. Knowledge and understanding about food preservation helps.

Comment: No problem. Ive been working in the food manufacturing area as a production manager for 6 years now. So I've  seen the bubbles and know where it comes from. I know a bit about irrational fears and how it can eat at you. Hope it helped.